# help rewriting in functional style

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning Scala as my first functional-ish language. As one of the problems, I was trying to find a functional way of generating the sequence S up to n places. S is defined so that S(1) = 1, and S(x) = the number of times x appears in the sequence. (I can't remember what this is called, but I've seen it in programming books before.)

In practice, the sequence looks like this:

```
  S = 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 ...
```

I can generate this sequence pretty easily in Scala using an imperative style like this:

```
  def genSequence(numItems: Int) = {
    require(numItems > 0, "numItems must be >= 1")
    var list: List[Int] = List(1)
    var seq_no = 2
    var no     = 2
    var no_nos = 0
    var num_made = 1

    while(num_made < numItems) {
      if(no_nos < seq_no) {
        list = list :+ no
        no_nos += 1
        num_made += 1
      } else if(no % 2 == 0) {
        no += 1
        no_nos = 0
      } else {
        no += 1
        seq_no += 1
        no_nos = 0
      }
    }
    list
  }
```

But I don't really have any idea how to write this without using `vars` and the while loop.

Thanks!

Comment: I have only read a bit on Scala, but something like this should get you started: `Stream.continually(x).take(S(x)).toList`. Write a recursive function using this as part of its definition - I just don't know Scala well enough to tell you what it should be.

Comment: Are you sure this sequence is unique? I think `1, 0, 0, 0, ...` also satisfies your criteria.

Comment: Seems to be Golomb's sequence: http://oeis.org/A001462

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code produces exactly the same sequence as yours:

```
val seq = Stream.from(1)
        .flatMap(Stream.fill(2)(_))
        .zipWithIndex
        .flatMap(p => Stream.fill(p._1)(p._2))
        .tail
```

However, if you want to produce the [Golomb sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_sequence) (that complies with the definition, but differs from your sample code result), you may use the following:

```
val seq = 1 #:: a(2)
def a(n: Int): Stream[Int] = (1 + seq(n - seq(seq(n - 2) - 1) - 1)) #:: a(n + 1)
```

You may check [my article](http://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/) for more examples of how to deal with number sequences in functional style.

Comment: As Kevin correctly pointed-out, two flatMaps and a zipWithIndex are overkill in the refactored snippet. Moreover, the Stream is an overkill, because the computation doesn't refer to previously computed values. So "def it = Iterator.from(1).flatMap(n => Iterator.fill(n/2 + 1)(n))" is even more efficient refactoring. However, refactoring is not enough to produce correct Golomb sequence. The second code snippet uses Stream with recurrence relation to achieve the goal.

Comment: If memory serves, you still would need a `Stream` in the refactored version, as `Iterator` doesn't provide a `flatMap` operation. I may be wrong on this point though (not so easy to check on my phone, scaladoc isn't touch-screen friendly)

Comment: @Kevin `Iterator` does have `flatMap` method.

Answer (score 10):

Pavel's answer has come closest so far, but it's also inefficient. Two `flatMap`s and a `zipWithIndex` are overkill here :)

My understanding of the required output:

- The results contain all the positive integers (starting from 1) at least once
- each number `n` appears in the output `(n/2) + 1` times

As Pavel has rightly noted, the solution is to start with a `Stream` then use `flatMap`:

```
Stream from 1
```

This generates a `Stream`, a potentially never-ending sequence that only produces values on demand.  In this case, it's generating `1, 2, 3, 4...` all the way up to Infinity (in theory) or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (in practice)

Streams can be mapped over, as with any other collection. For example: `(Stream from 1) map { 2 * _ }` generates a Stream of even numbers.

You can also use `flatMap` on Streams, allowing you to map each input element to zero or more output elements; this is key to solving your problem:

```
val strm = (Stream from 1) flatMap { n => Stream.fill(n/2 + 1)(n) }
```

---

So... How does this work?  For the element `3`, the lambda `{ n => Stream.fill(n/2 + 1)(n) }` will produce the output stream `3,3`.  For the first 5 integers you'll get:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2, 2
3 -> 3, 3
4 -> 4, 4, 4
5 -> 5, 5, 5
etc.
```

and because we're using `flatMap`, these will be concatenated, yielding:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...
```

Streams are memoised, so once a given value has been calculated it'll be saved for future reference.  However, all the preceeding values have to be calculated at least once.  If you want the full sequence then this won't cause any problems, but it does mean that generating `S(10796)` from a cold start is going to be slow! (a problem shared with your imperative algorithm).  If you need to do this, then none of the solutions so far is likely to be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt from a Scala tyro.  Keep in mind I don't really understand Scala, I don't really understand the question, and I don't really understand your algorithm.

```
def genX_Ys[A](howMany : Int, ofWhat : A) : List[A] = howMany match {
    case 1 => List(ofWhat)
    case _ => ofWhat :: genX_Ys(howMany - 1, ofWhat)
}

def makeAtLeast(startingWith : List[Int], nextUp : Int, howMany : Int, minimumLength : Int) : List[Int] = {
    if (startingWith.size >= minimumLength) 
      startingWith 
    else 
      makeAtLeast(startingWith ++ genX_Ys( howMany, nextUp), 
                 nextUp +1, howMany + (if (nextUp % 2 == 1) 1 else 0), minimumLength)
}

def genSequence(numItems: Int) =  makeAtLeast(List(1), 2, 2, numItems).slice(0, numItems)
```

This seems to work, but re-read the caveats above.  In particular, I am *sure* there is a library function that performs `genX_Ys`, but I couldn't find it.

**EDIT** Could be

```
def genX_Ys[A](howMany : Int, ofWhat : A) : Seq[A]  = 
   (1 to howMany) map { x => ofWhat }
```

Comment: The library function you're looking for is `List.fill`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a translation of your code to a more functional style:

```
def genSequence(numItems: Int): List[Int] = {
  genSequenceR(numItems, 2, 2, 0, 1, List[Int](1))
}


def genSequenceR(numItems: Int, seq_no: Int, no:Int, no_nos: Int, numMade: Int, list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
 if(numMade < numItems){
   if(no_nos < seq_no){
     genSequenceR(numItems, seq_no, no, no_nos + 1, numMade + 1, list :+ no)
   }else if(no % 2 == 0){
     genSequenceR(numItems, seq_no, no + 1, 0, numMade, list)
   }else{
     genSequenceR(numItems, seq_no + 1, no + 1, 0, numMade, list)
   }
  }else{
    list
  }
}
```

The genSequenceR is the recursive function that accumulates values in the list and calls the function with new values based on the conditions. Like the while loop, it terminates, when numMade is less than numItems and returns the list to genSequence.

This is a fairly rudimentary functional translation of your code. It can be improved and there are better approaches typically used. I'd recommend trying to improve it with pattern matching and then work towards the other solutions that use Stream here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very direct "translation" of the definition of the Golomb seqence:

```
val it = Iterator.iterate((1,1,Map(1->1,2->2))){ case (n,i,m) =>
    val c = m(n)
    if (c == 1) (n+1, i+1, m + (i -> n) - n)
    else (n, i+1, m + (i -> n) + (n -> (c-1)))
}.map(_._1)

println(it.take(10).toList)
```

The tripel (n,i,m) contains the actual number n, the index i and a Map m, which contains how often an n must be repeated. When the counter in the Map for our n reaches 1, we increase n (and can drop n from the map, as it is not longer needed), else we just decrease n's counter in the map and keep n. In every case we add the new pair i -> n into the map, which will be used as counter later (when a subsequent n reaches the value of the current i).

**[Edit]**

Thinking about it, I realized that I don't need indexes and not even a lookup (because the "counters" are already in the "right" order), which means that I can replace the Map with a Queue:

```
import collection.immutable.Queue

val it = 1 #:: Iterator.iterate((2, 2, Queue[Int]())){
  case (n,1,q) => (n+1, q.head, q.tail + (n+1))
  case (n,c,q) => (n,c-1,q + n)
}.map(_._1).toStream
```

The Iterator works correctly when starting by 2, so I had to add a 1 at the beginning. The second tuple argument is now the counter for the current n (taken from the Queue). The current counter could be kept in the Queue as well, so we have only a pair, but then it's less clear what's going on due to the complicated Queue handling:

```
val it = 1 #:: Iterator.iterate((2, Queue[Int](2))){
  case (n,q) if q.head == 1 => (n+1, q.tail + (n+1))
  case (n,q) => (n, ((q.head-1) +: q.tail) + n)
}.map(_._1).toStream
```