# Struggle against habits formed by Java when migrating to Scala

Tags: java, scala, migration

What are the most common mistakes that Java developers make when migrating to Scala?

By mistakes I mean writing a code that does not conform to Scala spirit, for example using loops when map-like functions are more appropriate, excessive use of exceptions etc.

EDIT: one more is using own getters/setters instead of methods kindly generated by Scala

Comment: They use 4-space indentation.

Comment: @Kevin It is not possible to mark a queston "community wiki" anymore. It has to be brought to the attention of a moderator.

Comment: @Daniel - shame... I liked the feature, and I *am* a moderator, how did I miss this change?

Comment: @Kevin It has been this way for quite a while now, as a matter of fact. I can even look up the blog where it was announced, but, then again, so can you. ;-)

Comment: Let me state, for the record, that I don't consider this question "not a real question". I do think it should go to programmers.stackexchange.com instead. It's just the way things are done nowadays.

Comment: @Daniel: on the "community status" front, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192

Comment: I completely agree with Daniel - this is very obviously a question of genuine interest to those coming from Java to Scala

Comment: @Kevin You are not a moderator. Moderators have this [shiny diamond](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) next to their name.

Comment: @NullUserException - so having enough rep to use moderator tools is a distinct status from being a moderator... Glad they made *that* one nice and clear!

Comment: I think a similar question is discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One obvious one is to not take advantage of the nested scoping that scala allows, plus the delaying of side-effects (or realising that everything in scala is an expression):

```
public InputStream foo(int i) {
   final String s = String.valueOf(i);
   boolean b = s.length() > 3;
   File dir;
   if (b) {
       dir = new File("C:/tmp");
   } else {
       dir = new File("/tmp");
   }
   if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
   return new FileInputStream(new File(dir, "hello.txt"));
}
```

Could be converted as:

```
def foo(i : Int) : InputStream = {
   val s = i.toString
   val b = s.length > 3
   val dir = 
     if (b) {
       new File("C:/tmp")
     } else {
       new File("/tmp")
     }
   if (!dir.exists) dir.mkdirs()
   new FileInputStream(new File(dir, "hello.txt"))
}
```

But this can be improved upon a lot. It could be:

```
def foo(i : Int) = {
   def dir = {
     def ensuring(d : File) = { if (!d.exists) require(d.mkdirs); d }
     def b = { 
       def s = i.toString
       s.length > 3
     }
     ensuring(new File(if (b) "C:/tmp" else "/tmp"));
   }
   new FileInputStream(dir, "hello.txt")
}
```

The latter example does not "export" any variable beyond the scope which it is needed. In fact, it does not declare any variables *at all*. This means it is easier to refactor later. Of course, this approach *does* lead to hugely bloated class files!

Comment: You only saved one line of code and lost a ton of readability.

Comment: @ryeguy: this is a contrived example, so minimizing loc was hardly my aim. Your claim about readability may be valid, but as you start to "scale up" methods like this to >20 lines, the argument that the Java verson is more readable starts to wear very thin. You end up with an ungainly mess where the *components* of the method are all mixed up with one another; difficult to refactor because you cannot see what is used where. Furthermore if you follow a standard pattern (all inner defs at the top, body at the bottom), readability does not necessarily suffer. Method body can be a single line.

Answer (score 9):

It's quite simple: Java programmer will tend to write [imperative style code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), whereas a more Scala-like approach would involve a [functional style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

- That is what Bill Venners illustrated back in December 2008 in his post "[How Scala Changed My Programming Style](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/programming_style.html)".
- That is why there is a collection of articles about "[Scala for Java Refugees](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-1)".
- That is how some of the SO questions about Scala are formulated: "[help rewriting in functional style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135383/help-rewriting-in-functional-style)".

Answer (score 7):

A couple of my favourites:

1. It took me a while to realise how truly useful Option is. A common mistake carried from Java is to use null to represent a field/variable that sometimes does not have a value. Recognise that you can use 'map' and 'foreach' on Option to write safer code.
2. Learn how to use 'map', 'foreach', 'dropWhile', 'foldLeft', ... and other handy methods on Scala collections to save writing the kind of loop constructions you see everywhere in Java, which I now perceive as verbose, clumsy, and harder to read.

Comment: Don't forget `collect`, one of my favorites.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if we could get null deprecated without screwing up Java integration..

Comment: @Malvolio "border-methods" (even if Scala methods can be called from Java, many are just *not suitable* to be called from Java and thus I view that Java-interop must be a deliberate layer exposed)

Answer (score 3):

A common mistake is to go wild and overuse a feature not present in Java once you "grokked" it. E.g. newbies tend to overuse pattern matching(*), explicit recursion, implicit conversions, (pseudo-) operator overloading and so on. Another mistake is to misuse features that look superficially similar in Java (but ain't), like for-comprehensions or even `if` (which works more like Java's ternary operator `?:`).

(*) There is a great cheat sheet for pattern matching on Option: http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Comment: I tend to overuse `Trait` a lot and then sometimes I have trouble understanding my own code.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it gave an idea of what constitutes overuse of these features.

Comment: The different nature of the Scala "for" is something that can't be overemphasized.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't adopted lazy vals and streams so far.

In the beginning, a common error (which the compiler finds) is to forget the semicolon in a for:

```
 for (a <- al;
      b <- bl
      if (a < b)) // ...
```

and where to place the yield:

```
 for (a <- al) yield {
     val x = foo (a).map (b).filter (c)
     if (x.cond ()) 9 else 14 
 }
```

instead of

```
 for (a <- al) {
     val x = foo (a).map (b).filter (c)
     if (x.cond ()) yield 9 else yield 14  // why don't ya yield!
 }
```

and forgetting the equals sign for a method:

```
 def yoyo (aka : Aka) : Zirp { // ups!
     aka.floskel ("foo")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using if statements. You can usually refactor the code to use if-expressions or by using filter.

Using too many vars instead of vals.

Instead of loops, like others have said, use the list comprehension functions like map, filter, foldLeft, etc. If there isn't one available that you need (look carefully there should be something you can use), use tail recursion.

Instead of setters, I keep the spirit of functional programming and have my objects immutable. So instead I do something like this where I return a new object:

```
class MyClass(val x: Int) {
    def setX(newx: Int) = new MyClass(newx)
}
```

I try to work with lists as much as possible. Also, to generate lists, instead of using a loop, use the for/yield expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using Arrays.

This is basic stuff and easily spotted and fixed, but will slow you down initially when it bites your ass.

Scala has an Array object, while in Java this is a built in artifact. This means that initialising and accessing elements of the array in Scala are actually method calls:

```
//Java
//Initialise
String [] javaArr = {"a", "b"};
//Access
String blah1 = javaArr[1];  //blah1 contains "b"

//Scala
//Initialise
val scalaArr = Array("c", "d")  //Note this is a method call against the Array Singleton
//Access
val blah2 = scalaArr(1)  //blah2 contains "d"
```

Comment: Not so much a bad habit as a 'speed bump' when migrating from Java to Scala. For a long while, I kept writing `scalaArr[1]`, only catching the error on compile/run (mainly using REPL). I didn't really internalise this as most of the dev I perform is _still_ java.